# Catastrophic backtracking issue

Tags: regex, backtracking

I am running into an issue with a regex pattern when no match is found.

The regex pattern that I use is:

```
^(?:".*?",){4}"(?:.*?)Cookie:\s(?:.*?)Routing=(.*?);
```

As test data I use something in the likes of:

```
"a","b","c","d","POST: /portal/start.asp HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: myhost\r\nCookie: w1n0_er=xxxx; routxing=yyyy;"x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x",
```

When the 'routing' parameter is found, all works well. However, when the routing parameter is not found by excluding it from the test data, the regex keeps searching. I found out by other posts that this is caused by catastrophic backtracking but I cannot seem to find a way to avoid it.

Comment: A good way to start would be to change `".*?"` to `"[^"]*"`.

Comment: What do you actually want to search for?

Comment: Since you already know where to search, extract the 5th quoted string first, and after check if it contains what you want.

Comment: Your input contains lots of double quoted strings. That's one of two main  reasons why you encounter catastrophic backtracking on `".*?"` pattern which expands too many times to satisfy engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Narrowing your question to:

> How to avoid catastrophic backtracking?

Regex side: Be as specific as possible, as [Rawing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1222951/rawing) said in his comment, changing `".*?"` to `"[^"]*"` will reduce drastically the number of required backtrack for the engine.

Input site: When possible, reduce the input to the smallest part you need without loosing information. Here, changing your input from:

```
"a","b","c","d","POST: /portal/start.asp HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: myhost\r\nCookie: w1n0_er=xxxx; routxing=yyyy;"x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x","x",
```

to

```
"POST: /portal/start.asp HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: myhost\r\nCookie: w1n0_er=xxxx; Routing=yyyy;"
```

and regex to:

```
^".*?Cookie:\s.*?Routing=(.*?);
```

will help a lot.